# How can I rewrite the Taylor series in order to find the interval of convergence?

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

So I have a taylor series $f(x)=\ln(x)$ at $a=8$ is given by: the sum from $0$ to infinity of $cn(x-8)$ . (see photo)

I have all the coefficients but, how do I rewrite a taylor polynomial in a ratio of polynomials so that I can use power series and ratio test  to find the interval of convergence ?

The ratio of polynomials I have from the coefficients are

$((-1)^n1*?) / (8^n*n!)$

This is for freshman calculus

[image]

Comment: Since you have all of the coefficients, what is your formula for $c_n$? With that in hand, the ratio of two successive terms of the series is $| a_{n + 1} / a_n | = |c_{n + 1} / c_n | |x - 8|$.

Comment: hmmm alright, I have (-1)^n-1*?/(8^n*n!). What goes where the question mark is? I know it should probably involve 8....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x) = \ln(x)$$

$$f'(x)=\frac1x, c_1 = \frac1{8\cdot 1!}$$

$$f''(x)=-\frac1{x^2}, c_2 = -\frac1{8^2\cdot 2!}$$
$$f^{(3)}(x)=\frac2{x^3}, c_3 = \frac{2}{8^3\cdot 3!}=\frac{1}{8^3\cdot 2}$$

$$f^{(4)}(x) = -\frac{3!}{x^4}, c_4 = -\frac{3!}{8^4\cdot 4!}=-\frac1{8^4\cdot 4}$$

For $n\ge 1$, 
we have  $c_n=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{8^n \cdot n}$

Hence $$f(x) = \ln (8) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{8^n \cdot n}\cdot (x-8)^n$$

and it converges if $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{8^{n+1}(n+1)}(x-8)^{n+1}}{\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{8^nn}(x-8)^n} \right|<1$$

$$\frac{|x-8|}8<1$$

Also, remember to check the boundary of the interval.